# Problem with Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
char *str = NULL;
str = Operation(argv[1]);
cout << Cal(str);
```

Operation function return a pointer, but I really don't know why `str` in `Cal` is `null`. 
in line 2, it still has content.  What am I missing?

---

```
char* Operation(char* name)
{
    fstream file(name,ios::in);
    char c;
    char stack[256]; int count_stack = -1;  
    char result[256]; int count_result = -1;
    while ( !file.eof() )
    {
        c = file.get();
        if ( c=='(')
        {
            count_stack++;
            stack[count_stack] = c ;
        }
        else if ( isOperand(c) )
        {
            count_result++;
            result[count_result] = c;
        }
        else if ( isOperator(c) )
            if ( isOperator( (stack[count_stack]) )>0 )
                if ( isOperator(c) > isOperator( stack[count_stack] ) )// dua ra so sanh khi trong stack co n>=1 ptu
                {
                    count_result++;
                    result[count_result] = c;
                }
                else
                {
                    count_result++;
                    result[count_result] = (stack[count_stack]);
                    stack[count_stack]= c;
                }
            else
            {
                count_stack++;
                stack[count_stack] = c ;
            }
        else if ( c==')') // Neu gap dau ngoac dong se lay het phan tu ra den khi gap ngoac mo
        {
            while( stack[count_stack] != '(')
            {
                count_result++; 
                result[count_result] = stack[count_stack];
                count_stack--;
            }
            count_stack--;
        }
    }
    while ( count_stack >=0 )
    {
        count_result++; 
        result[count_result] = stack[count_stack];
        count_stack--;
    }
    return &result[0];
}
```

This is the Operation Function . I'm really bad in pointer :P

Comment: Can you post the contents of the Operation function and the Cal function ?

Comment: @George Stocker: It is perfectly ok to have NULL as is.

Comment: if there is no danger in sharing your code for us to look into, would be a great step towards solving your problem.

Comment: SOrry , I edit the code :| It only has one *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, firstly, in your Operation function you're returning a pointer to a temporary stack array.  In Operation you declare `char result[256]` as a temporary stack variable.  The 256 bytes you allocate here are ONLY valid for the duration of the Operation function.  So using the pointer to `result` after Operation returns will cause undefined behavior.

To fix this, you have a few options:

1) You can allocate `result` on the heap, (using the `new` operator)

2) Even better, instead of returning a `char*` pointer, simply return an `std::string` object so you don't need to worry about allocating/deallocating memory.

3) Finally, if your program is single-threaded, you can also simply make `char result[256]` a static variable by declaring `static char result[256]`.  This way, the pointer will be valid even after you return from Operation.

I would recommend option 2.

Comment: In Operation function, I return the address of the first element in result so I can use result array :|
"you're returning a pointer to a temporary stack array" I don't see it . Can you point it out :D ( I'm noob )

Comment: My teacher ask me to do math ( operand, operator ) with no container in stl . So I don't use string .
Thanks so much . Stackoverflow is great :)

Comment: Okay, well since you can't use a string, you can use option 3 (declare the array as static), as long as you are sure your program is not multi-threaded.  (Static variables are not thread-safe)

Comment: Thanks salvia so much. It's solved . I don't know much about thread-safe . I'll research :)

Comment: `result' is local to your function.  Logically, it ceases to exist when you return from the function.

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a pointer to a pointer. As you say, `Operation` returns a pointer (to what?). You ought to get a diagnostic (type mismatch).

Comment: but still its not possible to store void* in char** ?